# A relation on the set with four elements which is reflexive, but not transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Give an example of a relation on the set A with 4 elements which is reflexive, but not transitive.

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6\}$ be the set with 6 elements.

I have worked out the relation $R = \{(1,1),(2,4),(4,2),(5,5)\}$

I believe this is reflexive because they are all elements of A but not not transitive as $2,4 4,2$ are there but not $4,4$.

Is this  correct?

Comment: Reflexive is defined if for every a in A, (a,a), belongs in relation R. Clearly that is not the case in yours.

Comment: so you cannot cannot give such a relation?

Comment: What you've made is a relation that is _symmetric_ but not transitive.

Comment: No relation on a set of *six* elements, which consists of only *four* tuples, can possibly be reflexive . . .

Answer (score 2):

Consider the relation R on the above set given as :

$R={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(4,2),(2,6)}$

For every element $a$ in $A$ we have $(a,a)$ in $R$ hence it is reflexive, but also $(4,2)$ and $(2,6)$ belongs in $R$ but not $(4,6)$ hence it is not transitive